# Como creo un formulario con 2 botones en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, formularios, tablas, body

Quisiera poder hacer un formulario con 2 botones y al pinchar en cada boton me aparezca un contenido diferente. ya he probado varias veces cambiando el código, añadiendo o quitando cosas pero ni aun asi.el codigo es el siguiente:..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<head>  
 <form method="post" action=" "
 name="datos1" id="datos1">
 Nombre: <input type="text"
 name="tabla1" id="tabla1">
 </form>
 <script>
function dibujatabla()
{
    document.write("<h2>Tabla de mis enlaces favoritos</h2>");

    document.write("<table border=1>");
    document.write('<tr id="fila1"><th>Buscadores</th><th>Noticias</th><th>Música</th></tr>');
    
    document.write('<tr id="fila2"><td> <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a> </td> <td><a href="https://elpais.com/">Diario El pais</a></td> <td><a href="https://www.spotify.com/">Spotify</a></td></tr>');

    document.write('<tr id="fila3"><td><a href="https://es.yahoo.com/?p=us">Página de Yahoo</a></td><td><a href="https://www.elmundo.es/">Diario El mundo</a></td><td><a href="https://www.deezer.com/es/">Deezer</a></td></tr>');
    
    document.write('<tr id="fila3"><td><a href="https://www.bing.com/?setlang=es">Página de Bing</a></td><td><a href="https://www.bbc.com/mundo">BCC news</td><td><a href="https://www.youtube.com/">Youtube</td></tr>');

    document.write('</table>');


 document.
 getElementById("tabla1").
 value;
 
 document.forms.datos1.
 elements.tabla1.value;
 
 document.forms[0].
 tabla1.value;
 document.datos1.tabla1.value;
 }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type='button' value=' Dibuja Tabla. '
        onclick='dibujatabla();'>
    </form>
</body></html>



<!DOCTYPE html>  
<head>   
 <form method="post" action=" "
 name="datos2" id="datos2">
 Nombre: <input type="text"
 name="tabla2" id="tabla2">
 </form>
 <script>
function dibujatabla()
{
    document.write("<h1>Tabla con mis fotos</h1>");

    document.write("<table border=1 >");
    
    document.write('<tr id="fila1"><th><img src="Valladolid/Valladolid1.jpg"> </th>   <th><img src="Valladolid/Valladolid5.jpg"></th>    </tr>');
    
    document.write('<tr id="fila2"><td> <img src="Valladolid/Valladolid3.jpg">  </td>     <td> <img src="Valladolid/Valladolid4.jpg"></td> </tr>');
    

    document.write('</table>');

 document.
 getElementById("tabla2").
 value;
 
 document.forms.datos2.
 elements.tabla2.value;
 
 document.forms[0].
 tabla2.value;
 document.datos2.tabla2.value;
 }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type='button' value=' Dibuja Tabla.  '
        onclick='dibujatabla();'>
    </form>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimado:
Revisando su código, pude notar que las funciones que crean las tablas tienen el mismo nombre, por tanto, cuando usted presiona cualquiera de los 2 botones, se queda con la última funcion dibujatabla() declarada, que es la de mas abajo. tendría que declarar las funciones con distintos nombres para que se diferencien cuando estas sean llamadas, podría ser algo así:

```js
function dibujatabla1()
{
    document.write("<h2>Tabla de mis enlaces favoritos</h2>");

    document.write("<table border=1>");
    document.write('<tr id="fila1"><th>Buscadores</th><th>Noticias</th><th>Música</th></tr>');

    document.write('<tr id="fila2"><td> <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a> </td> <td><a href="https://elpais.com/">Diario El pais</a></td> <td><a href="https://www.spotify.com/">Spotify</a></td></tr>');

    document.write('<tr id="fila3"><td><a href="https://es.yahoo.com/?p=us">Página de Yahoo</a></td><td><a href="https://www.elmundo.es/">Diario El mundo</a></td><td><a href="https://www.deezer.com/es/">Deezer</a></td></tr>');

    document.write('<tr id="fila3"><td><a href="https://www.bing.com/?setlang=es">Página de Bing</a></td><td><a href="https://www.bbc.com/mundo">BCC news</td><td><a href="https://www.youtube.com/">Youtube</td></tr>');

    document.write('</table>');


 document.
 getElementById("tabla1").
 value;

 document.forms.datos1.
 elements.tabla1.value;

 document.forms[0].
 tabla1.value;
 document.datos1.tabla1.value;
 }
```

```html
<form>
  <input type='button' value=' Dibuja Tabla. ' onclick='dibujatabla1();'>
</form>
```

Como se aprecia del código anterior, se le cambio el nombre a una de las funciones de js por dibujatabla1(), además de cambiarla dentro del html del botón al cual desea que muestre esta tabla. El resto se deja igual.

Espero le sea de utilidad.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
function appendTable(table = 0) {
        let hmtl_append = "";
        switch (table) {
          case 0:
            hmtl_append += `<h2>Tabla de mis enlaces favoritos</h2><table border=1>`;
            hmtl_append += `<tr id="fila1"><th>Buscadores</th><th>Noticias</th><th>Música</th></tr>`;
            hmtl_append += `<tr id="fila2"><td> <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a> </td> <td><a href="https://elpais.com/">Diario El pais</a></td> <td><a href="https://www.spotify.com/">Spotify</a></td></tr>`;
            hmtl_append += `<tr id="fila3"><td><a href="https://es.yahoo.com/?p=us">Página de Yahoo</a></td><td><a href="https://www.elmundo.es/">Diario El mundo</a></td><td><a href="https://www.deezer.com/es/">Deezer</a></td></tr>`;
            hmtl_append += `<tr id="fila3"><td><a href="https://www.bing.com/?setlang=es">Página de Bing</a></td><td><a href="https://www.bbc.com/mundo">BCC news</td><td><a href="https://www.youtube.com/">Youtube</td></tr>`;
            hmtl_append += `</table>`;
            break;
          case 1:
            hmtl_append += `<h1>Tabla con mis fotos</h1>`;
            hmtl_append += `<table border=1 >`;
            hmtl_append += `'<tr id="fila1"><th><img src="Valladolid/Valladolid1.jpg"> </th>   <th><img src="Valladolid/Valladolid5.jpg"></th>    </tr>`;
            hmtl_append += `<tr id="fila2"><td> <img src="Valladolid/Valladolid3.jpg">  </td>     <td> <img src="Valladolid/Valladolid4.jpg"></td> </tr>`;
            hmtl_append += `</table>`;
            break;
          default:
    
        }
        document.getElementById("table-container").innerHTML = hmtl_append;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form method="post" action=" " name="datos1" id="datos1">
        <input type='button' value='Mis enlaces favoritos' onclick='appendTable(0);' />
        <input type='button' value='Mis fotos' onclick='appendTable(1);' />
        Nombre: <input type="text" name="tabla1" id="tabla1">
        <div id="table-container">
        </div>
      </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Para esto la tabla la almacenamos como string, podrás realizar un for para imprimir cada row de la misma y así evitar generar varios string, yo utilice un contenedor dentro del formulario aquí es donde generare el HTML de la tabla con la función **innerHTML**.

Comment: muchísimas gracias :)